# Google app engine, template: the entity key becomes something like a url-encoded string

Tags: google-app-engine, templates

I tried to pass a list of tuples to the template system, including the entity key. However, the key passed to the template appear to be something like a url-encoded string. How to solve the problem? Thanks.

view:

```
items = []
for i in range(50):
  if prod[i]:
      items.append((prod[i].name, prod[i].key, someList[i]))
  else
      items.append((None, None, otherList[i]))
```

html template:

```
{% for item in items %}
   ...
   <img src="/image?entity_id={{item.1}}" />
   ...
{% endfor %}
```

The entity key in the image request turned out to be the following:

**/GET /image?entity_id=%3Cbound%20method%20Product.key%20of%20%3Cmodel.Product%20object%20at%200xad63f2c%3E%3E HTTP/1.1" 404 -**

Comment: It's url encoded. What tempting framework are you using ? and how are you storing this value ?

Comment: Also the key is never stored url encoded. And it's a url friendly key without escapes etc. Something is done wrong here.

Comment: as well:    prod[i].key ?  shouldn't it be .key()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using the original db library rather than ndb. `key` is a method - as you can see from the value, which says "bound method Product.key...". You need to call it:

```
items.append((prod[i].name, prod[i].key(), someList[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the url safe encoded string provided by NDB API in your URLs, since it's more elegant compared to the raw Key.

Thus, you can create it by:

```
items.append((prod[i].name, prod[i].key.urlsafe(), someList[i]))
```

In your handler, you can reconstruct the Key based on the encoded urlsafe string as:

```
my_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=your_encoded_string)
```

For more information, you can take a look at [NDB Key class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass).